# Unresolved class in tool.context

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I create a new project have an error

> "Unresolver class "MainActivity" in tool.context=".MainActiviity"

If I click "run app" it shows that default activity not found

Tried to write like this: tool.context = "com.example.android.myapplication", but it still reports that default activity not found. Projects that worked fine a few days ago now have this problem too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: Post your manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Does your `package` or `applicationId` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle` file is same as you `Activity`'s package structure?

That is `com.example.android.myapplication` ?

Comment: Yes, it is "com.example.android.myapplication5" in AndroidManifest.xml, build.gradle and MainActivity